# How to find new start and new end based on round trip?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following datatype:

```
id      start        end       count            Time             Trip
001     Paris      London        01      2016-05-20 10:50:00      Yes
015     Paris      London        01      2016-05-19 11:50:00      Yes
002     Prague     Vienna        15      2016-05-18 17:55:00      No
003     Frankfurt  London        01      2016-05-17 21:15:00      Yes
015     London     Paris         08      2016-05-21 13:50:00      No
003     Barcelona  Vienna        15      2016-05-19 03:20:00      No
003     London     Barcelona     01      2016-05-18 06:45:00      Yes
002     Vienna     Prague        15      2016-05-19 02:45:00      No
```

*I would like to group the data by their id and time;*

and identify round trip. In short if it satisfies the following condition,

1."end" city of first line is equal to "start" city of next line AND

2."start" city of first line is equal to "end" city of next line,

then "new start" is the start of first line and "new end" is the end of first line.

For example, lets consider the id 002,

```
002     Prague     Vienna        15      2016-05-18 17:55:00      No
002     Vienna     Prague        15      2016-05-19 02:45:00      No
```

It is a round trip. So "new start" is prague and "new end" is vienna.

Thank you! Same in case of id 015.

Comment: so your final dataframe has 2 ids for 002 and 2 for id 015?

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach

```
#create mirror values
df['M1'],df['M2'] = df['start'] + df['end'],df['end'] + df['start']

#keep values that exist back and forth
df = df.loc[(df.M1.isin(df.M2))].iloc[:,:6]

#drop where id is less than one
df.drop(df.id.count() <= 1,inplace=True)

#sort output
df.sort_values(by=['id','Time'],ascending=[True,True],inplace=True)
```

which results in

```
   id   start     end  count             Time Trip
2   2  Prague  Vienna     15  5/18/2016 17:55   No
7   2  Vienna  Prague     15   5/19/2016 2:45   No
1  15   Paris  London      1  5/19/2016 11:50  Yes
4  15  London   Paris      8  5/21/2016 13:50   No
```

Answer (score 0):

a. Groupby `id`:

```
df.groupby("id")
```

b. Sort by `Time`":

```
x.sort_values("Time") # x is a subset of df with identical `id`
d = x.sort_values("Time")[["start", "end"]].values
```

c. Check if adjacency pair of records has a interchange of `start` and `end`.

```
isloop = [all(i[0] == i[1][::-1]) for i in zip(d[:-1], d[1:])]
```

So the full code is:

```
def func(x):
    d = x.sort_values("Time")[["start", "end"]].values
    isloop = [all(i[0] == i[1][::-1]) for i in zip(d[:-1], d[1:])]
    return x[:-1][isloop]
df.groupby("id").apply(func)
```

The result is:

```
                     Time Trip count     end    id   start
id
2  2  2016-05-18 17:55:00   No    15  Vienna   2.0  Prague
15 1  2016-05-19 11:50:00  Yes    01  London  15.0   Paris
```